Adaptive Text Flutter
I've been having trouble making my app adaptive to different text sizes. I've tried popular packages like ScreenUtil and several others, but nothing seems to resolve the problem. I also created a class to make my app responsive overall, but it doesn't affect the text sizes. Additionally, I tried using FittedBox, but it doesn't work on some of the texts. What should I do?
Below is my Responsive class, which I typically use in a page as "responsive.screenHeight / ratio" or "responsive.screenWidth / ratio" after creating an object of it.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Responsive {
  late BuildContext context;
  late double screenHeight;
  late double screenWidth;
  Responsive(BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        (MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top +
            MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom);
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -
        (MediaQuery.of(context).padding.left +
            MediaQuery.of(context).padding.right);
  }
}



Check this Widget it's so useful where you can set max and min lines and fonts and they can expand and shrink relatively with child text
